# MySQL Workbench Error Code: 1074. Column length too big for column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, union

I am trying to create a report from a table in MySQL Workbench (Version 8.0.13) and creating several tables from selects in the process:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
AS 
(SELECT 
process, 
owner, 
... 
COUNT(*) AS number_of_s,
AVG(pay) AS avg_pay, 
SUM(labor_cost) AS sum_of_labor_costs
FROM
old_table
GROUP BY
process,
owner);
```

`CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` works fine.

> Error Code: 1074. Column length too big for column

is thrown when I try to `UNION` two newly created tables when mysql workbench encounters a column of type `double(0,2)`.

So when I run

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_by_month
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
new_table_by_month_1 
UNION 
SELECT 
* 
FROM new_table_by_month_2;
```

and both new_table_by_month_1 and new_table_by_month_2 has same columns, the procedure runs until it encounters sum_of_labor_costs (type double(0,2)) then it returns the error:
**Error Code: 1074. Column length too big for column sum_of_labor_costs  (max = 65535); use BLOB or TEXT instead**

I understand that the column type is probably causing this error, but why, and what is the issue here?

How could I optimise my UNION so it would work?

**UPDATE If I Don't create just select:**

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    new_table_by_month_1 
UNION 
SELECT 
    * 
FROM new_table_by_month_2;
```

it works. The problem occurs when I want to create a new_table from the select * from a union select * from b;

Comment: I see double(0,2) as type when click on the info icon next to the table name and look at the columns tab.

Comment: In order to eliminate mysqlworkbench interpreting the table definition what do you see in the output from a show create <table>

Comment: `DOUBLE(0,2)` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a subquery for build the main  select

```
    CREATE TABLE new_table_by_month
    SELECT *
    from (
      select  * 
      FROM  new_table_by_month_1 
      UNION 
      SELECT *  
      FROM new_table_by_month_2
    )  t 
    ;
```

in this way the data type for creation should be more clear. 
anyway be sure that the two query select coherent and coresponding data type.. seems you are selecting a wrong column in correspondance of sum_of_labor_costs ..check if the sequence of the columns data type are the same 
try also inverting

```
   CREATE TABLE new_table_by_month
    SELECT *
    from (
      select  * 
      FROM  new_table_by_month_2
      UNION 
      SELECT *  
      FROM new_table_by_month_1
    )  t 
    ;
```

Comment: which data type are involved in the tables ??

Comment: also update your  question and add the tables schema

Comment: The table contains 143 columns, that is why I try not to define the schema myself, but let mysql workbench do the job.

Comment: ok .. but you must be sure that the two schema corresponding  ..  and you have not a blog column in wrong place.  +